# Not able to load partial view as modal when called from _Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my Core 2.0 project I am trying to load a partial view to modal div when called from _Layout.cshtml but nothing happens. On click of **Create New User** I am trying to load partial view on modal popup. Below is code-

//_Layout.cshtml

```
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
<li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="/" onclick="CreateUser()">Create New User</a></li>
```

//Index.cshtml of Home

```
<div class="modal fade" id="AppointmentSchedule" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header btn-primary">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="AppointmentModalLabel"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="ScheduleAppointment"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

//Javascript

```
function CreateUser() {
            var url = appSetting + "Home/CreateUser";
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: url,
                data: null,
                dataType: "html",
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#ScheduleAppointment").html('');
                    $("#ScheduleAppointment").html(data);
                    $("#AppointmentSchedule").modal('show');
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    $("#divScheduleAppointment").html('');
                }
            })
        }
```

//Home Controller

```
  public ActionResult CreateUser()
      {
        return PartialView("_CreateUserHome");
      }
```

On debugging I realize that after Ajax success it calls Index action method of Home controller(that should not be) and may be it is causes page refresh and popup may get close. But what is it's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code, when user clicks on the anchor tag,  the browser do a normal link click behavior, which is navigating to the `href` attribute value of the clicked link element. If you want show the modal dialog instead of that, you should prevent this default behavior.

You may pass an `event` object to the `CreateUser` method

```
<a href="/" onclick="CreateUser(event)">Create New User</a>
```

and in your method, call the `preventDefault` method, which will stop the normal link click behavior(navigating to to the `href` value)

```
function CreateUser(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = appSetting + "Home/CreateUser";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function (data)
        {
            $("#ScheduleAppointment").html(data);
            $("#AppointmentSchedule").modal('show');
        },
        error: function (result)
        {
            $("#divScheduleAppointment").html('');
        }
    })
}
```

A suggestion: If it is not a navigational link, Consider using a button instead of an anchor tag.

Comment: It solved the problem but when I click second time onward it is not opening and I get console error **$(...).modal is not a function** until I refresh page. This happens same even with button

Comment: Make sure the partial view you load into the modal body does not include any new script tags (check the response of the ajax call). Make sure you use `return PartialView()` instead of `return View()` in your `CreateUser`

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution is to add return false to your event handler:

```
    <li><a href="/" onclick="CreateUser(); return false;">Create New User</a></li>
```

This will suppress default behavior.